# How Do I solve "Sequence contains no elements" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an index view that gets a parameter from an Action link. Sometimes there won't be a record and in that case I want the @Model.Count to simply show 0. That was working just fine. I then need a button to pass that same parameter to a Create view to add a new (initial) record and display on the previous index page. This is where I hit a problem.

```
<input class="btn  btn-sm btn-info" type="button" value="Add To Roster" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Enrollments", new {enrollments_CurrentSites = Model.First().Enrollments_CurrentSite}, null)' "/>
```

If there is no record, instead of showing a count of 0, I now get an error "Sequence Contains No Elements". I thought that maybe there is a null Model and tried to check for it, but no go. If there is one or more records, then the Count is displayed and the "Add To Roster" button performs as expected. 
Can someone help me solve this error?

Error Code:

```
 @model IEnumerable<SlamJammersData.Model.Enrollments>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rosters";
}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                     @if (Model == null)
                {
                    <h4>Roster count: 0</h4>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>
                        <h4>Roster count: @Model.Count() </h4>

                    </p>
                }

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">

                    <p>

                            <input class="btn  btn-sm btn-info" type="button" value="Add To Roster" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Enrollments", new {enrollments_CurrentSites = Model.First().Enrollments_CurrentSite}, null)' "/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Attendance" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Player</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartTime)</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach(var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new{id = item.Id})
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.Id})
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sending code:

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Rosters", "Index", "Enrollments", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
```

Comment: If the model contains no items then `Model.First()` will throw an exception. You will need the pass the `enrollments_CurrentSites` parameter using a property of a view model or a `ViewBag` property.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The ViewBag Property works for this situation.

<input class="btn  btn-sm btn-info" type="button" value="Add To Roster" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Enrollments", new {enrollments_CurrentSites = ViewBag.SiteId}, null)' "/>

Comment: Check first if there records exists or not by Model.Any() then, You can use Model.FirstOrDefault().Enrollments_CurrentSite or Model.First().Enrollments_CurrentSite